# Python program to give full address as output after detection country and state name

Tags: python

I have the image of address in png format. I want to write a program in such a way that after extracting the text from image, the program should identify that if there is country name and state name in the address, then it should display both country name and state name and display the whole address as output.

For instance, I have taken the dictionary of Country names but for all states of world, how should I manage. Can anyone help?

For image extraction, this is the methodology I followed:

```
path_to_tesseract = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
path_to_image = 'path of image'
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract
img = Image.open(path_to_image)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

The address is:

Subash Mittal

Near Mother Diary

Close to Radha Krishna Mandir
Gurgaon Harayana 122001
India

Tel : 9999999999

The text I am able to extract but after this, What could be the program. Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, actually I want to make a python program where the address, that I have mentioned above, can be splitted into list, after this the program that we'll write should be able to identify adjacent strings of country name, then display output as Country name --- India  , State name --- Harayana and also display full address.  It should be able to identify this full string as address.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to take a public dataset on internet and use it to store a set of states and a set of countries. Some examples of public datasets: https://data.world/datasets/countries .

Another option is to use some public API. Maybe Google Maps API. You can use it to search for latitude/ longitude of an address. If it fails, you consider the address to be invalid.

Comment: This reads as more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: I think it's adapted for this question. My message gives ideas to solve the problem. This kind of question is the one that once you have the idea, you can easily google.

Comment: I mean, for some kind of questions , giving ideas can be as valuable as giving an exact answer.